# Getting random field name when exporting mysql to csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to export a mysql table to csv. The issue I am having is it puts in a field name called 'id' every time the code increments. So after the first field, I get id. Two more fields after that, I get id. Three fields after that, I get id field. I have no idea why that would happen. Any help is greatly appreciated. (Note: I know not to use mysql, and I generally use mysqli, but this is what I am using for right now).
Here is my code:

```
    $hostname = "localhost"; //SET SERVER/HOSTNAME
    $dbusername = "username"; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
    $dbname = "dbname"; //SET DATABASE NAME
    $dbpassword = "password"; //SET DATABASE USERNAME

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select Data Base");

    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");



$query = "SELECT * FROM v88374";

$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) ."|" . "\t";

    echo $header;
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = $value . '|' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

print "$header\n$data";

exit();
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html)?

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary the OP clearly stated `Note: I know not to use mysql, and I generally use mysqli, but this is what I am using for right now` I think we get the point...

Comment: @amaster507, if you get the point, then you wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I would be using

```
fputcsv()
```

Example in the documentation below

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be a better approach with the next changes, it's a little bit easier:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM v88374";
$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM v88374";
$rfields = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
$rows = array();
$fields = array();

$tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $rfields );
while($tmp)
{
    $fields[] = $tmp['Field'];
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $rfields );
}
@mysql_free_result($rfields);

$tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $export );
while($tmp)
{
    $rows[] = $tmp;
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $export );
}
@mysql_free_result($export);

$header = implode("|\t", $fields);
$ifields = count($fields);
echo '<pre>';var_dump($ifields, $fields);
$data = '';
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $line = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $ifields; $i++)
        $line .= ($line == '' ? '' : "\t").$row[$fields[$i]];
    $data .= $line."\n";
}

echo $header."\n".$data;
exit();
```

Or

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM v88374";
$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
$rows = array();
$fields = array();

$tmp = mysql_fetch_field ( $export );
while($tmp)
{
    $fields[] = $tmp->name;
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_field ( $export );
}

$tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $export );
while($tmp)
{
    $rows[] = $tmp;
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $export );
}
@mysql_free_result($export);

$header = implode("|\t", $fields);
$ifields = count($fields);
echo '<pre>';var_dump($ifields, $fields);
$data = '';
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $line = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $ifields; $i++)
        $line .= ($line == '' ? '' : "\t").$row[$fields[$i]];
    $data .= $line."\n";
}

echo $header."\n".$data;
exit();
```